# In code editor for policies why does validate-jwt claim separator get removed if it's a space?r

Tags: azure, azure-api-management

When setting up policies for `auth0` in api management I noticed that if I set up a `validate-jwt` policy with a `claim` whose separator is a space the next time I load the policy in the code editor the space is removed. If I save the policy with the separator set to space then save it my validation works correctly. If I then come back to edit the policies in the code editor the separator is now set to "".  I would expect to see `separator =" " not separator=""`.

It took me a while to figure out this was happening and have been manually putting the space back in each time I edit policies. Hopefully this can be fixed.

Comment: I also tried to do expressions like @(" ").  That made my request 404. I tried @{return " ";}. That doesn't work either.

Comment: I would think space is supported as some auth providers use it as their scope separator.

Answer (score 1):

We fixed this issue and update will be available in a couple hours.
Sorry for inconvenience